# jQuery Simple Slider not setting the values for both text boxes

Tags: jquery, slider

I am following the tutorial [jQuery Simple Slider Examples](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/demo.html)

My index.html goes as under

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/simple-slider.js"></script>
        <link href="css/simple-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/simple-slider-volume.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>

<body>
        <h1>Home Loan EMI and Eligibility Calculator</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Gross Monthly Income</td>
                <td><input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="15000,2000000" data-slider-step="1000"> </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtGMI"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Current EMIs</td>
                <td><input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,2000000" data-slider-step="1000"> </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtTCEMI">
            </tr>
        </table>

          <script>
            $("[data-slider]")          
                .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) 
                {                   

                     $('#txtGMI').val(data.value);
                     $('#txtTCEMI').val(data.value);
                });
          </script>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, (I know there is something wrong in my code) if I change the value of **Gross Monthly Income** slider, the textbox values for both **Total Current EMIs** and **Gross Monthly Income** are also getting updated and vice versa.

How can I set the textbox values only corresponding to that particular slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to add am id to `inputs` and bind event separately

*HTML*, I have added `slider1` and `slider2` as IDs of slider

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Gross Monthly Income</td>
        <td><input id='slider1' type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="15000,2000000" data-slider-step="1000"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtGMI"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total Current EMIs</td>
        <td><input id='slider2' type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,2000000" data-slider-step="1000"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtTCEMI">
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
$("#slider1")          
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data)         {       
        var xx = "Rs. " + ConvertTOINR(data.value);
         $('#txtGMI').val(xx);
    }); 

$("#slider2")          
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) 
    {       
        var xx = "Rs. " + ConvertTOINR(data.value);
         $('#txtTCEMI').val(xx);
    });
```

Comment: Where is the  `ConvertTOINR` function declared?

Comment: @taxicala. OP modified the question, It was defined in the separate `script` block in global scope

Answer (score 2):

I would do as follows in order to only have one bind code:

HTML with `data-target` addition:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Gross Monthly Income</td>
        <td><input id='slider1' type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="15000,2000000" data-slider-step="1000" data-target="#txtGMI"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtGMI"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total Current EMIs</td>
        <td><input id='slider2' type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,2000000" data-slider-step="1000" data-target="#txtTCEMI"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtTCEMI">
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the JS code with one single bind call:

```
$("[data-slider]").bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {                  
    $($(this).data('target')).val(data.value);
});
```